# numpy python code array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
Array_temp = array_1 tarray_1

print(Array_temp)
[list([1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]) list( [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0])]

Array_sub = array_1 array_1

print(Array_mul)
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <i python-input-11-c5dc21502aaf> in <module() --> 1 Array_sub = 

array_1-array_1

2 print (Array_mul)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

array_di = array_1 *array_1

print (array_di)
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <i python-input-13-09997f8001 f6> in <module () -->1 array_di = array_1*array_1

2 print (array_di)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Adding arrays together succeeded, but failed to subtract or multiply arrays
Tell me what's wrong with my code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply a **[mcve]**.

Comment: You need to describe what you expect the code to do and what it is actually doing, preferable with samples.

Comment: Those aren't arrays.  They are lists. Lists can be joined, +, or replicated , *5, only,

Answer (score 0):

I think this replicates what you are trying to do:

```
In [70]: arr = np.array([list([1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]), list( [2.0, 4.0, 
    ...: 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0])])
In [71]: 
In [71]: arr
Out[71]: 
array([list([1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]),
       list([2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0])], dtype=object)
In [72]: arr-arr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-c5b907903880> in <module>()
----> 1 arr-arr

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
In [73]: arr*arr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-4ca35a17b454> in <module>()
----> 1 arr*arr

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

You start with an array that contains 2 lists of different sizes.  Because of that, the array is an `object` dtype, with shape (2,).

`arr-arr` delegates the action to the elements of `arr`, and then complains that subtraction is not defined for lists.

Addition is defined for lists - it is just list join

```
In [74]: arr+arr
Out[74]: 
array([list([1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]),
       list([2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0])],
      dtype=object)
```

`list*list` isn't defined either.  But `arr*2` produces the same thing as `Out[74]`.

If the lists are the same size, then we get a 2d array, and this math is defined:

```
In [76]: arr = np.array([list([1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0]), list( [2.0, 4.0, 
    ...: 6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0])])
In [77]: arr
Out[77]: 
array([[1., 3., 7., 1., 3., 7.],
       [2., 4., 6., 8., 2., 4.]])
In [78]: arr-arr
Out[78]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [79]: arr*arr
Out[79]: 
array([[ 1.,  9., 49.,  1.,  9., 49.],
       [ 4., 16., 36., 64.,  4., 16.]])
```